# How to pass an email address securely to a web application X embedded inside a web application Y

Tags: web-application, appsec, email, http

The scenario I'm trying to address is this:

There is a web application Y which has an authenticated user. Inside Y, web application X is hosted (which belongs to a different domain).

When X is launched from Y, we want the authenticated email address from Y to go to X.

X is launched by hitting a url belonging to domain X.com

Is it a concern if we simply launch X using the url and appending the email address as a query string to the same url?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how the execution is.

If your sending the email as an plain text (none-encrypted) there are severe issues concerning integrity (Did the client-side change the email address?)
Assuming both domains are in your control this can be solved by encrypting the email address with your private key.